# Spring batch jobs | Does the read/write happen in the same thread?

Tags: java, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am running a spring batch job with the reader reading a file and returning a list and the writer consuming that list and writing to a file.

Does the following mean that this reader/writer will run in one thread? Is there a guarantee that the same thread will be used for the reader and writer process. If so, does the following configuration control that.

```
<batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter">
```

Background:
I am using a static thread-local variable to collect the errors associated with the reads and writes and printing them at the end of the write process. If spring batch uses different threads to work on the process, that would force me to change the strategy.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Chunks are groups of data that will be processed together, without committing anything until the entire chunk is written. You can read about chunks in spring batch documentation [Spring Batch Chunk Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html).

To make Spring Batch multi threaded you need to define tasklets, like for example ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

So, if you are not defining any tasklet, you can assume that your batch job will be p